# operator+ overload error. Unable to return reference to object

Tags: c++, oop, reference, operator-overloading

There is the class:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    double value;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        this->value = 0;
    }

    MyClass(double value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }

    MyClass& operator + (MyClass & outerObj);
};
```

Why does that overload work:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator + (MyClass & outerObj)
{
    MyClass retObject(this->value + outerObj.value);
    return retObject;
}
```

But does this one not?

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator + (MyClass & outerObj)
{
    return MyClass(this->value + outerObj.value);
}
```

VC++ issues a warning:

> MyClass::MyClass(double value)
>
> +3 overloads
>
> initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

I can not understand what the problem is. After all, it returns essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of the 1st code snippet, you're trying to return a reference being bound to local object. The local variable will be destroyed when get out of the function, then the returned reference is always dangled.

The problem of the 2nd code snippet, you're trying to bind a temporary object to lvalue-reference to non-const, which is ill-formed.

You should change the `operator+` from return-by-reference to return-by-value, which will make both returning local object or temporary object work fine, and keep you away from the above troubles. e.g.

```
MyClass MyClass::operator + (const MyClass & outerObj) const {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Usually also a good idea for the `operator+()` itself to be `const`.   i.e. `MyClass MyClass::operator + (const MyClass & outerObj) const`.   It is rarely a good idea for an expression `a + b` to be able to modify `a`.